# Creating a Media Player in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a media player in JavaFX but I am getting an error during runtime.  My classes are as follows:

Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Player player = new Player("file:///C:\Users\Momin\Downloads\Lesson 1A- Building Layouts Videos\01 - Introduction");
        Scene scene = new Scene(player, 852, 480, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;

public class Player extends BorderPane {

    Media media;
    MediaPlayer player;
    MediaView view;
    Pane mpane;

    public Player(String file) {
        media = new Media(file);
        player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        view = new MediaView(player);
        mpane = new Pane();

        mpane.getChildren().add(view);

        setCenter(mpane);

        player.play();
    }

}
```

When I run Main.java, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/1323468230.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 35: file:///C:/Users/Momin/Desktop/Java Projects/Player/Videos.sample.mp4
at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Unknown Source)
at application.Player.<init>(Player.java:17)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:13)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/192199497.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/186276003.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/29678400.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 35: file:///C:/Users/Momin/Desktop/Java Projects/Player/Videos.sample.mp4
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Please help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"file://c:/Users/Momin/Downloads/ .... yourFile.ext"` instead. Your path is invalid because `\` is escape character

- Don't forget file's extension.
- Also put `//` (double slash) in front of the drive : `file://c`
- There won't be any `space`on your path. ***/Lesson 1A- Building Layouts Videos/***  `<-- incorrect`

Comment: Also note you're creating a string that specifies a URI here (see [`Media` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media-java.lang.String-)), so (for example) you can't have whitespace. The safest way is to create a `File` object first and then to call `toUri()` and `toString()`.

Comment: Yeap, agree with @James_D.